# Getting text inline with a path in SVG without strikethrough

Tags: svg, jointjs

I'm trying to get the text to appear inside the line for a connection with the line getting out of the way, as per image below.

[image: target]

Just putting using the line as a textPath for the image isn't working because when I make the text inline, the line continues through the text.
[image: Strikethrough sample]

I've got a solution that works for straight paths.  I measure the text length, and the full path length, and then split it into 3 separate paths.  I draw a stroke on the 1st and 3rd path, with the middle path used for the textPath.

I'm not able to get this to work for anything other than a straight line path though as I can't measure the text or work out the lengths of the each section.

I'm using JointJS, but a pure pseudocode/SVG answer would be just as helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to put a white (or whatever your background colour is) rectangle on top of the line and underneath the text.

```html
<svg width="400px" height="100px">
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="350" y2="50" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"/>
  <rect x="125" y="40" width="150" height="20" fill="white"/>
  <text x="200" y="54" text-anchor="middle" fill="blue">Text inline with arrow</text>
</svg>
```

Or, instead of a rectangle, put a duplicate of the text, but make it white and give it a thick stroke.  The advantage of this method is that you don't have to fuss about trying to work out the correct size for the rectangle.

```html
<svg width="400px" height="100px">
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="350" y2="50" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"/>
  <text x="200" y="54" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" stroke="white" stroke-width="5">Text inline with arrow</text>
  <text x="200" y="54" text-anchor="middle" fill="blue">Text inline with arrow</text>
</svg>
```

One thing about this method is that if the gaps in the letters, or between the words, is large enough, the line will show.  You may or may not find that desirable.

These are just two possible ways to do it. I can think of a few more, but they are a little more involved.

Comment: Great solution.  For the gaps between words I replaced spaces in the white text with the unicode block character that Micheal suggested and the result is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to create a text block that's the same length as your text that's just the Unicode block character with a fill equal to your background color and draw that before you draw your actual text path. (You need to add the dilation filter to paper over artifacts caused by arcs/curves - you may want to adjust the radius as necessary).

```html
<svg width="12cm" height="3.6cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 300" version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
<path id="MyPath"
      d="M 100 200 
         C 200 100 300   0 400 100
         C 500 200 600 300 700 200
         C 800 100 900 100 900 100" />

<filter id="dilatethis">
  <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="4"/>
</filter>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" y="-15" />

  <text font-family="monospace" font-size="42.5" fill="white" filter="url(#dilatethis)" >
<textPath xlink:href="#MyPath" startOffset="155" >
  &#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;&#9608;
</textPath>
  </text>


  <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="42.5" fill="blue">
<textPath xlink:href="#MyPath" startOffset="155" >
  Just imagine that this  
</textPath>
  </text>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers from Michael Mullany and Paul LeBeau, I've implemented this in JointJS, so am posting the changes needed.

Define a new shape model that extends `joint.dia.Link` eg: `joint.shapes.gary.InlineLabelLink`

Extend the markup in the shape model with two new text fields.  One for the label (inlineText), one for the mask that sits behind the label (inlineTextMask).

Add some attributes to make sure text is where it is needed.

Add a new property called "caption" which will hold the inline label text.

eg:

```
joint.shapes.gary.InlineLabelLink = joint.dia.Link.extend({

    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
    markup: [
        '<path class="connection" stroke="black" d="M 0 0 0 0"/>',
        '<path class="marker-source" fill="black" stroke="black" d="M 0 0 0 0"/>',
        '<path class="marker-target" fill="black" stroke="black" d="M 0 0 0 0"/>',
        '<path class="connection-wrap" d="M 0 0 0 0"/>',
        '<text class="inlineTextMask" />',
        '<text class="inlineText" />',
        '<g class="labels"/>',
        '<g class="marker-vertices"/>',
        '<g class="marker-arrowheads"/>',
        '<g class="link-tools"/>'
    ].join(''),
    attrs: {
        '.inlineText': {
            'dominant-baseline': 'central',
            'text-anchor': 'middle',
            'pointer-events': 'none',
            'font-size': 10
        },
        '.inlineTextMask': {
            'dominant-baseline': 'central',
            'text-anchor': 'middle',
            'pointer-events': 'none',
            'fill':'#ffffff',
            'stroke':'#ffffff',
            'stroke-linejoin':'smooth',
            'stroke-linecap':'round',
            'stroke-width': 8,
            'font-size': 10
        }
    },
    caption: 'TBD'
}, joint.dia.Link.prototype.defaults)});
```

Then create a new View class extending from `joint.dia.LinkView`

In that class we override the `update` function so it can draw the inline label in the right place.

```
joint.shapes.gary.InlineLabelLinkView =  joint.dia.LinkView.extend({

    update: function() {
        joint.dia.LinkView.prototype.update.apply(this, arguments);

        var inlinePath = this._V.connection.node.getAttribute('d');


        this._V.inlineText.text(this.model.get('caption'),
            {textPath: { d: inlinePath, startOffset:"50%" } });

        this._V.inlineTextMask.text(this.model.get('caption').replace(' ','\u9608'),
            {textPath: { d: inlinePath, startOffset:"50%" } });

        return this;
    }
});
```

The updated View class gets the path from the link, then applies this path to both the text mask and the text properties.  It uses the Vectorizer's text method to create the appropriate defs,textPath and tspan entries.

This does have the problem that sometimes the text can be upside down depending upon the direction of the link.  This can be resolved by reversing the direction of the path.

I've used a bespoke function for this (not shown), but there are libraries out there like https://github.com/SmartArtsStudio/smart-svg-path and  https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-reverse

```
    if (this.sourcePoint.x > this.targetPoint.x) {
        inlinePath = reversePath(inlinePath);
    }
```